# How to unlist objects in R and inner_join them without multiplying rows?

Tags: r, list, inner-join, quantmod

I am using R and the library `quantmod`  to import data as:

```
getSymbols("TMUS",from="2020-05-21", src="yahoo",frequency = "daily", format = "%Y-%m-%d") 
getSymbols("AAPL",from="2020-05-21", src="yahoo",frequency = "daily", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

and then I want to unlist them and give them a date column:

```
TMUS<- as.vector(unlist(TMUS$TMUS.Close)) %>% as_tibble() %>% add_column(date=index(TMUS),.before=1)
AAPL<- as.vector(unlist(AAPL$AAPL.Close)) %>% as_tibble() %>% add_column(date=index(AAPL),.before=1)
```

and finally inner join them to create a unique database:

```
data <- TMUS %>%
        inner_join(.,AAPL, by = "date")
```

The issue is that the inner join multiplies the number of the rows. I believe the reason is that both `TMUS` and `AAPL` are lists. I tried to unlist them by using `as.vector(unlist(.))`, but they are still lists.

Is there a way to obtain a dataset inner joining without multiplying the rows?

Comment: Please confirm you are also using `zoo`.

Comment: I am actually not using zoo, but I guess it may be imported by quantmod

Comment: Typo: `index(APPL)`?

Comment: Corrected, thanks!

Comment: Nothing here is a `list`, they are all `"data.frame"` (from `getSymbols`) or `c("tbl_df","tbl","data.frame")` (from your `as.vector(...)` stream). When I run `inner_join`, I start with 253 rows each and end with 253 rows total, I do not see your *"multiplying the rows"*. (`inner_join` only works on `data.frame`-like objects including tibbles, it will not work on vectors, so `unlist(.)` is not a usable approach.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (or use Ad in place of Cl if you want adjusted closes).  `AAPL`, `TMUS` and `both` will be xts objects.  If  you only want dates for which there is data in both series then use `na.omit(both)`.

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols(c("AAPL", "TMUS"))
both <- cbind(Cl(AAPL), Cl(TMUS))
```

If you have many stocks then try this approach:

```
getSymbols(c("AAPL", "TMUS"), env = e <- new.env())
both <- do.call("cbind", eapply(e, Cl))
```